# I reported a bug on launchpad a while ago and it seems to be fixed now, what should I do?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

I reported [the following bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1325008) back when I was still using Ubuntu 14.04 but it hadn't had any activity since.

I've updated my system since then, and I'm on 15.10 at the moment. And at this point, the bug seems to be fixed in this version.

I don't have access to a 14.04 installation so I cannot test if it has been fixed there, but I know it is fixed on 15.10.
Since 14.04 is an LTS release and it is still supported, it doesn't seem right to just mark the bug as "Fix Released".

What should I do in this case?

Should I just wait till the maintainer closes it? can I close it myself just for 15.10 and keep it open for 14.04?
For now, I left a comment on the bug asking the same. But I'd like to know what is the usual course of action in this case.

Comment: That someone will be me

Comment: Update my Ubuntu 14.04(in Virtualbox), and restarted, and opened a bunch of nautilus windows, and the 'bug' still exist. Close all, closes only the current window, as does `CTRL`-`Q`. Version: `GNOME nautilus 3.10.1`

Comment: A bug can be marked with individual status for each Ubuntu release ([like this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1534887))

Answer (score 0):

If you can't test it on Ubuntu 14.04, just leave it as it is.

Somebody will probably test it and report.